# What is the equivalent of /sudo:root@localhost:/ in windows?

Tags: microsoft-windows, tramp

What is the easiest way to access files that require admin privilege in windows?
I could see similar questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4470213/how-do-i-switch-to-admin-user-in-emacs-on-windows) and [here](https://superuser.com/questions/896122/open-file-with-emacs-as-administrator-on-windows).  But I think this would be the right forum to find the best solution for this problem.

Answer (score 5):

For Tramp, this is not available. One would need to write a new package tramp-runas.el or tramp-elevate.el, which implements it.

Since I'm not using MS Windows myself, it is unlikely that I'll implement this. However, contributions are welcome.

(I'm the Tramp maintainer)